# Ruby unable to find external programs in PATH environmental variable

Tags: ruby, windows

Can someone explain what's changed in Ruby when looking for programs in PATH? I know this used to work.

From **Windows Command Line** (exiftool is in C:\Windows\system32):

```
C:\>exiftool
Usage: exiftool [ -Alib.par ] [ -Idir ] [ -Mmodule ] [ src.par ] [ program.pl ]
   exiftool [ -B|-b ] [-Ooutfile] src.par
```

From **irb**:

```
`exiftool`
Errno::ENOENT: No such file or directory - exiftool
    from (irb):1:in ``'
    from (irb):1
    from C:/Ruby192/bin/irb:12:in `<main>'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could be off here, but don't you need to wrap that in a system call - i.e. execute it as if it's running on the command line? In IRB I can type any command I want that is a system command, and I get the same results you're seeing unless I wrap it as such:

`system("exiftool")`

For example, to display the list of files in the current directory in IRB, `dir` fails, but `system("dir")` works.

Comment: Are system("exiftool") and `exiftool` the same?

Comment: `system("exiftool")` is how you call `exiftool` from within IRB. They run the same command, ultimately. Simply typing `exiftool` *alone* within IRB will fail.

Comment: didn't realize it would remove my tickmarks: command is **tick** exiftool **tick**

Comment: Ah, gotcha. Well, the answer is still "no, they are not the same." You'll need to wrap it in a system call. I do get different output from IRB when putting ticks around just the command itself (no system method call), but it doesn't seem to actually run the command.